# Annoying border on react carbon focus Chrome

Tags: css, reactjs, outline

I am using Carbon React and i cannot figure out how to remove that annoying blue border on focusing on a checkbox.
I know that outline: none is the solution, but I cannot find on which attribute/element I should put it.
Even on Storybook of Carbon (http://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?path=/story/checkbox--checked) there is same issue when clicking on a Checkbox component. (only on Chrome)

Comment: put it on all elements if you want to remove it completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following style

```
.bx--checkbox:focus+.bx--checkbox-label::before, .bx--checkbox-label__focus::before, .bx--checkbox:checked:focus+.bx--checkbox-label::before, .bx--checkbox-label[data-contained-checkbox-state='true'].bx--checkbox-label__focus::before, .bx--checkbox:indeterminate:focus+.bx--checkbox-label::before, .bx--checkbox-label[data-contained-checkbox-state='mixed'].bx--checkbox-label__focus::before {
  border: 0
}
```

you might wanna change border style if removed all then you will not able to detect checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS class you looking to fix is this

```
.bx--checkbox-label::before, .bx--checkbox-label::after
```

write a custom class to override the action.

Answer (score 0):

For carbon design I could only make it work using:

```
      :focus{
        outline: 2px solid transparent !important;
        outline-offset: 2px !important;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.bx--checkbox-label::before, .bx--checkbox-label::after{
 outline: none !important;
}
```

This works for my case